# Ag-Grid-React-How to show no rows template dynamically?

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I tried to show no rows template of Ag Grid React table dynamically by using state but it didn't work. Do you have any idea ?

```
<AgGridReact
    className="ag-theme-alpine"
    animateRows="true"
    columnDefs={columnDefs}
    defaultColDef={defaultColDef}
    enableRangeSelection="true"
    rowData={rowData}
    rowSelection="multiple"
    suppressRowClickSelection="true"
    overlayNoRowsTemplate={message} // state of component
/>
```

This is my demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/QQH8qZ8vxzdMM0k5

Thank for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try creating your own Overlay Component?

You can take a reference from [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/component-overlay).

Comment: Tks you. I tried and it works but just when you change state and click show no rows loading again, it not update message of no rows component immediately. 

[link](https://plnkr.co/edit/Yy3Z1XLl8lcQNqIt?open=index.jsx)

Comment: If you want to make changes in the Grid, you will always have to use gridRef. In your scenario use gridRef.current.api.showNoRowsOverlay(); on each setMessage.
You will have to manage overlays on your end based on the row states. [link](https://plnkr.co/edit/GVFFsWOMOeZTiXrU?open=index.jsx)